# Serial communication protocols used in spacecrafts and airplanes

Tags: serial, protocol, serial-bus

I always see that CAN bus is used in automobiles for communication between nodes and for on board diagnostics and basically for the overall functioning of vehicle. What are the similar serial communication protocols used in airplanes and spacecrafts? I googled a lot but could not arrive at an exact answer.
Thank you

Comment: ARINC 429 self-clocked balanced differential pair serial protocol.

Comment: MIL-1553, MIL-1773, STANAG-3910

Comment: Thank you all , this gave me a good idea about the communications used! May I know the most popular and commonly used protocol?